# Creating an alphabetically sorted nlohmann::json subobject inside a nlohmann::ordered_json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

## Background Info

The [nlohmann JSON](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library offers two object orders:

1. `nlohmann::json`, which is alphabetically sorted
2. `nlohmann::ordered_json`, which keeps the order of insertion

So if we do this:

```
    nlohmann::ordered_json outer;
    outer["b"] = "b";
    outer["a"] = "a";
```

a dump would look like this (Order of insertion):

```
{
 "b": "b",
 "a": "a"
}
```

But with a `nlohmann::json` it becomes (Alphabetical Order of the Keys):

```
{
 "a": "a",
 "b": "b"
}
```

## What I want

I would like to mix the two orders. There should be an outer `ordered_json` which contains an inner `json`. A first naive try:

```
    nlohmann::ordered_json outer;
    outer["inner"] = nlohmann::json::object();
    outer["inner"]["b"] = "b";
    outer["inner"]["a"] = "a";
```

did not lead to the expected Result. Actual result:

```
{
 "inner": {
  "b": "b",
  "a": "a"
 }
}
```

What I have hoped for:

```
{
 "inner": {
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b"
 }
}
```

Is it possible to mix these two behaviors?

## Why I want it

I am aware that the JSON Standard states that a JSON Object is an unordered collection of key/value pairs. However, I am currently in a "but the customer wants it" scenario. I am also aware that I could add the inner values in an alphabetical order myself in the above toy example. However, knowing the exact keys isn't a luxury I have in the real project. Finding out which keys will be added at runtime and then sorting them myself before adding them to the JSON isn't possible either, as it would require massive refactoring of the project itself.

## What I found out so far

The `operator[]` seems to not care about the object that is about to be assigned while creating the subobject. When `operator=` is then called, it basically only moves existing Data in. So the following actually does lead to the expected result:

```
    nlohmann::ordered_json outer;
    nlohmann::json inner;
    inner["b"] = "b";
    inner["a"] = "a";
    outer["inner"] = inner;
```

However, this would again lead to a lot of refactoring. I would like the types to somehow "remember" their order.

Comment: *"but the customer wants it"*. Sigh

Comment: Have you investigated the nlohmann code to find out why your attempt above doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried populating the inner object first and then adding it to the outer object? https://godbolt.org/z/TzobffW34

Comment: I added a bit more information. @RetiredNinja Yep, I came up with that idea, too. But it would require too much refactoring in the existing project. It would be "nice" if the json objects somehow remembered their inner ordering.

Comment: The `ordered_json` is another specialization of `basic_json` (besides `json`) and thus not compatible. I fear it is currently impossible to create such a mixed json object. A `ordered_json` will only ever contain other `ordered_json`s and a `json` will only ever contain other `json`s.

Comment: What does the customer want? Does the customer even need to be inside the json file?  The order should not really matter for a piece of code reading the json. Also "the customer wants it" is all fine and good as long as they are willing to pay for the change.